# Why my calculations are wrong? Java reverse int problem

Tags: java, reverse

Here is my function that suppose to reverse and return giver integer:

```
public static int reverse(int x) {
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
    int result = 0, count = 0;

    while(x != 0)   {
        digits.add(x % 10);
        x /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(digits);
    int i = 0;
    while(count != 0) {
        result += digits.get(i) * (int) Math.pow(10, count - 1);
        System.out.printf("result: %d i: %d, count: %d - ", result,  i, count);
        System.out.printf("%d * %d\n", digits.get(i), (int) Math.pow(10, count - 1));
        count--;
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I encountered a problem. For example when I pass value of 1534236469 this is what happens:

```
    result: 410065408 i: 0, count: 10 - 9 * 1000000000
    .
    . 
    .
    1056389759
```

Why this is happening?
Also all tips on making this function better are welcome.

Comment: General debugging hint: You have lots of debug output. Does it not help you? When is the output not as you expect.

Switching to string representation, reverting, and switching to integer again might be another approach. `Integer.toString(int,int)` and `Integer(String)` might help.

Comment: The problem is with `9 * 1000000000` which goes beyond the maximum value an `int` variable can hold. When you assign a bigger value than the maximum allowed value, the value gets converted into a value from the other end i.e. `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` becomes `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also all tips on making this function better are welcome.

A simple implementation can be as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 123456789;
        int y = reverse(x);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    public static int reverse(int x) {
        return Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(x)).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123456789
987654321
```

Also, as already mentioned in the comment, when you assign a value bigger than the maximum allowed value to an `int` variable, the value gets converted into a value from the other end i.e. `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` becomes `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Therefore, for an integer like `1534236469` whose reverse is bigger than an `int` variable can hold, you should convert the reverse into a `long` value as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1534236469;
        long y = reverse(x);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    public static long reverse(int x) {
        return Long.parseLong(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(x)).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1534236469
9646324351
```

Comment: I see this an hacky way to do things. But well- it just does the work.

Answer (score 1):

Marcin, you can implement your reverse method like below,

```
public static long reverse(int x) {
    long reverseDigit = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        reverseDigit = reverseDigit * 10 + (x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return reverseDigit;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A more proper way to reverse an integer would be:

```java
int reverse(int n) {
    int reversed = 0;
    Boolean isNegative = n < 0;
    n = Math.abs(n);
    
    while(n > 0) {
        reversed = reversed * 10 + (n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
    
    if (isNegative)
        reversed *= -1;
    
    return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be, that the reverse of an int ist not always an int.

2147483647 is max int so,

9646324351

is too big and 1534236469 has no chance